# displaying new lines insted of br tag in xsl

Tags: xml, cdata

I am very new to xsl. I was changing an XML1 file to another XML2 file and that another XML2 file needs to be changed into a doc further.

I have some BR tags in my changed XML2 [This is my xml 2 file br tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzDtz.png) file, but when i convert those into a doc they are not displaying new lines rather they are displaying the same BR tags [this is the doc file with same br tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhKDD.png). Can anyone help me and tell how to solve this problem . It would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your XML samples as text not an images.

Comment: okay sure.   This is my xml 2 file br tags                                                     " - Check ALIVE message is send with known baud<br/>
- Assert that wrong baud rate<br/>
- Assert that all configured controllers send ALIVE message<br/>            "                                                                              also the doc file is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `<br/>` tags to return characters use `<xsl:text>` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
<xsl:text>

</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```